# Docker on CoreOS VM behind Corp proxy

Tags: kvm-virtualization, docker, libvirt, coreos

I have Docker on a CoreOS VM which runs on top of KVM.

VM Networking:

```
$ virsh net-edit libvirt

<network ipv6='yes'>
  <name>libvirt</name>
  <uuid></uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address=''/>
  <domain name='testbed.net' localOnly='yes'/>
  <dns>
    <host ip='192.168.121.104'>
      <hostname>m00.testbed.net</hostname>
    </host>
  </dns>
  <ip address='192.168.121.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.121.100' end='192.168.121.254'/>
      <host mac='' name='m00.net' ip='192.168.121.104'/>
      <bootp file='/pxelinux.0' server='192.168.121.2'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

docker.conf:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --dns x.x.x.x
Environment="https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:9080" "http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:9080" "no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1"
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
TasksMax=1048576
[Install]
Also=docker.socket
```

As soon as I run a docker container on the VM, I have no internet access on the host machine anymore.

```
$ sudo apt update
0% [Connecting to proxy (x.x.x.x)] [Connecting to proxy(x.x.x.x)]
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: How did you set up the VM networking?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated my question with VM networking setup.